# Xquery loop producing too many results. Bad "for" statement?

Tags: xml, database, xquery, basex

I have thousands of XML files that I need to perform an XQuery on.

This is what the XML looks like that I am querying, format is consistent:

```
   <Archive xmlns="http://www.xxxx.com/egAr/1.0" Location="file://xxxxxx/Digital_Archive/773592.zip" Version="1.0">
  <General Application="xxxx 16.0.1 - Build 1108 - Sep 30 2016" Author="xxxx@xxxx1" ModificationDate="2018-02-07T08:04:10-05:00" Server="xxxxxxx"/>
  <Job CSREmail="" Category="Digital" Category2="MCSD904LAYOUT" Category3="Mat HSLPETG10022 / S257 petg 50m" Category4="No" Category5="xxxxx" Category6="2" Category7="xxxxxx" Created="2016-03-07T09:33:15-05:00" CreatedFrom="xxxxxx" CustomerID="xxxxxx" CustomerJobReference="xxxxxxx" JobFolder="xxxxxxx" Name="773592" OrderID="773592" ProjectID="773592" SubOrderID="">
    <Description>xxxxxxx</Description>
  </Job>
  <Customer ID="332420" Name="xxxxxxx"/>
  <JobParams>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.No Across" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.No Around" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.Spacing across" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.Spacing around" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.Fronts around" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.Fronts across" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.Backs across" Value="0"/>
    <JobParam Name="steprepeat.Backs around" Value="0"/>
  </JobParams>
</Archive>
```

This is my Xquery:

```
for $t in //@Category2,
  $v in //@OrderID
let $d := "MCHT65780LAYOUT"
where $t = $d
order by $v
return concat ("Job: ",$v, "   Die: ", $t)
```

It produces more or less what I am looking for, but I have something wrong with the "for" loop, where I am getting infinite results and BaseX stops at 500,000 results. If I only put one item in the "for" statement, I get the correct number of results, but I need to see the "OrderID" and the "Category2" in the results.

Basically I want to search for the $d and see what jobs used that value.

---

Michael Kay's answer below worked like a charm. I also figured out how to produce results from a partial match of with the "contains" function:

```
declare namespace a="http://www.xxxx.com/egAr/1.0";
for $j in //a:Job
let $t := $j/@Category2
let $v := $j/@OrderID
let $d := "67"
order by $v
where ($t [contains (.,$d)]) 
return concat ("Job: ",$v, "   Die: ", $t)
```

Comment: Your query will always return (number-of-Category2-attributes)*(number-of-OrderID-attributes) results, since you're telling it to iterate over the instances of the latter that exist anywhere in the document once for each of the former. This is what a nested `for` loop will do in pretty much any language -- I'm hard-pressed to see how this could be read with a reasonable expectation of any other behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you don't want to consider all pairs of `@Category2` and `@OrderId` that appear anywhere in the document, but only pairs that appear on the same Job element.

You could write that as

```
declare namespace a="http://www.xxxx.com/egAr/1.0";
for $j in //a:Job
let $t := $j/@Category2
let $v := $j/@OrderID
let $d := "MCHT65780LAYOUT"
where $t = $d
order by $v
return concat ("Job: ",$v, "   Die: ", $t)
```

But I would probably write it as:

```
declare namespace a="http://www.xxxx.com/egAr/1.0";
for $j in //a:Job[@Category2 = "MCHT65780LAYOUT"]
order by $j/@OrderID
return $j/concat("Job: ", @OrderID, "   Die: ", @Category2)
```

Comment: That you so much Michael, I’ll try this out on Monday, when I get back to work. I appreciate the help so much.